# Reference nuget packages in html files

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have added Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker NuGet package. Using one of the examples, I created a code similar to this:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:130px;">
         <div class="form-group">
             <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                </span>
                </span>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
              daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
          });
       });
     </script>
  </div>
```

But I get an error on my page. Here is the error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Schedule:137)
at e (jquery.min.js:2)
at t (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I understand that I need to add scripts and links to css files. How can I do it if I do not see any datatimepicker scripts in my wwwroot folder? How do I reference that script in my html files when the package was brought via NuGet manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core projects use Package References,
so there's no clean way to get your scripts from a nuget package.

They're in this directory `%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages`.

For example, installing jQuery will install the scripts in this path `C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\jquery\1.8.0\Content\Scripts`.

Besides, Microsoft recommends using a package manager like libman or npm for js libraries while nuget will handle assemblies.

### Referencing js libraries using libman:

(Right click on your js libraries folder):

[image: Step1]

Then search for the library using this format: `libraryname@version`

[image: Step2]

Comment: How do I create a link or script tag then?  <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/username/.nuget/packages/bootstrap.v3.datetimepicker.css/4.17.45/content/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" /> Like this?

Comment: @ValK Pulling js libraries from nuget packages is a .NetFramework projects feature where the scripts are placed in your project but this isn't the case. Just use a package manager like `libman` its cleaner and you can keep track of your client side libraries via `libman.json`.
And what you're doing won't work and not recommended at all!

Comment: @ValK Updated my answer.